# Proving this statement for improper integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The statement says that if $f(x)$ is differentiable, $\ |f´(x)|$ is bounded for all $x$, and $$\int_0^{\infty} |f(x)| \,dx < +\infty,$$then 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0.$$  I´m not sure how to use the hypothesis here, any hint or help?

Comment: Please detail exactly what hypothesis you are speaking of

Comment: that the derivative of $f(x)$ is bounded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to require that $|f(x)-f(y)| \le L |x-y|$ for some constant $L$.
(This is implied by the hypotheses.)

Note that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_x^\infty |f(x)|dx = 0$.

Suppose $c=|f(x_0)| >0$. Then $\int_{x_0}^\infty |f(x)| dx \ge {c^2 \over 2L}$.

In particular, $\int_{x_0}^\infty |f(x)| dx \ge {(\sup_{x \ge x_0} |f(x)|)^2 \over 2L}$.

Combining these results shows that $\limsup_x |f(x)| = 0$, or equivalently,
$f(x) \to 0$.

Comment: The argument of copper.hat is valid but too terse. Here are some details: $\int_{x_0} ^{\infty} |f(x)| dx \geq \int_{x_0} ^{x_0+c/L} |f(x)| dx$ Now $|f(x)| \geq |f(x_0)|-|f(x)-f(x_0)| \geq |f(x_0)|-L|x-x_0|$. Integrate from $x_0$ to $x_0 +c/L$ and compute the integral of the last term explicitly. This gives the inequality in fourth line of the proof. Now note that $\int_{x_0} ^{\infty} |f(x)| dx \geq \int_{x} ^{\infty} |f(x)| dx$ for any $x>x_0$. Appying what we just proved with $x_0$ changed to x and then taking sup. over $x \geq x_0$ we get the next step.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, the little picture I can draw in 5 seconds takes significantly longer to draw on the computer and upload. Progress, I suppose...